# Delete all but the 4 newest directories

Tags: bash, shell

I want to delete all but the 4 newest directories in my parent directory. How would you do this in Bash?

Comment: You cannot retrieve the creation time of files or directories as is it not stored anywhere. The closest you can get is inode change time: http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part3/section-1.html and adding or removing files from directories changes the inode.

Comment: ... though adding or removing files from a child directory does *not* change a parents inode.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ls -atrd */ | head --lines=-4 | xargs rm -rf
```

**Edit:** added 'a' argument to ls

Comment: this will leave 4 most recently modified directories instead of the 4 most recently created, won't notice directories starting with a dot, head will break for names containing newlines, xargs will break for names containing whitespace, and rm will print an error message if there's nothing to delete.

Comment: Good points. I have now added 'a' to ls to capture directories with a dot, and grepped to get rid of the current and parent directories, but you're right. This is a simple answer with some important limitations as you have pointed out.

Comment: Correction: no grep is needed to filter the current and parent directory as they are not shown by ls */

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify if you mean “delete all directories but the four newst ones” or “delete everything (files and directories) except for the four newest directories”.

Please also note that creation times are not known for directories. One can only tell when a directory was last modified, that is, had files added, removed or renamed.

Answer (score 1):

you could do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

#store the listing of current directory in var
mydir=`ls -t`
it=1

for file in $mydir
    do
        if [ $it -gt 5 ]
        then
            echo file $it will be deleted: $file
            #rm -rf $file
        fi
        it=$((it+1))
    done
```

(remove the # before rm to make it really happen ;) )

Answer (score 0):

Another, BSD-safe, way to do it, with arrays (why not?)

```
#!/bin/bash
ARRAY=( `ls -td */` )
ELEMENTS=${#ARRAY[@]}
COUNTER=4
while [ $COUNTER -lt $ELEMENTS ]; do
  echo ${ARRAY[${COUNTER}]}
  let COUNTER=COUNTER+1
done
```